# Google Maps v2 calls System.gc() explicitly? Or how to find call to the System.gc()?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with `Google Maps v2` for `Android`.

I need to display some `View` over the map's marker, so I am updating its position every 16ms to keep 60fps.

And I got a problem with that code:

```
Point targetPosition = getMap().getProjection()
    .toScreenLocation(mTrackingMarkerPos);
```

Because it seems that it causes explicitly calls to the `System.gc()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`.

So I got this in log output:

```
03-12 15:00:24.362  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 122K, 10% free 12710K/14116K, paused 11ms+11ms, total 115ms
03-12 15:00:25.583  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 123K, 10% free 12711K/14116K, paused 7ms+4ms, total 100ms
03-12 15:00:26.845  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 123K, 10% free 12711K/14116K, paused 11ms+6ms, total 104ms
03-12 15:00:28.056  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 217K, 10% free 12710K/14116K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 98ms
03-12 15:00:29.287  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 121K, 10% free 12712K/14116K, paused 11ms+7ms, total 112ms
03-12 15:00:30.499  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 123K, 10% free 12712K/14116K, paused 7ms+4ms, total 87ms
03-12 15:00:31.760  19135-19135/my_fake_package_name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 126K, 10% free 12711K/14116K, paused 7ms+4ms, total 130ms
```

**As you can see, GC_EXPLICIT can pause my app for about 100ms!**

So my approach to keep 60fps is not achievable because of Google Maps v2 :(

If I comment that line, GC_EXPLICIT calls will disappear. I think that problem in Google Maps v2, I checked their .class files but I did not find any calls to `System.gc`, so may be I am wrong...

If you know how to find call to the `System.gc()` I will be glad to know it too, or guys from Google can help me with this issue?

**P.S.** Asked this on gmaps-api-issues: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6483&thanks=6483&ts=1394624273

Comment: "If you know how to find call to the System.gc()" -- get a job at Google, join the Maps team, and take a look at their code. The Play Services SDK is closed-source. "guys from Google can help me with this issue?" -- what issue? You cannot change the Play Services SDK code. You cannot assume how long a call to a third-party API will take. In particular, many Maps V2 API calls involve IPC to the Play Services app. I would focus instead on trying to avoid calling this every frame, but instead only when the coordinates will differ (e.g., on a camera change).

Comment: @CommonsWare haha, very funny :) But I can not avoid calling this every frame, I already optimized every instruction in this every frame runnable: storing last positions, min heap allocations and so on, but GC_EXPLICIT produced by GMaps... Btw: OnCameraChange calls are too low-frequently to draw custom Info Window right near to the marker

Comment: "Btw: OnCameraChange calls are too low-frequently to draw custom Info Window right near to the marker" -- you are not drawing a custom info window. Instead, you have chosen to "display some View over the map's marker". Perhaps the right answer is for you to use a custom info window, in which case it is Maps V2's job to keep the info window in the same position relative to the marker.

Comment: I checked my code which runs every 16ms, it takes 0-2ms to run on my nexus4, so I do not think that I can optimize it more.

Comment: @CommonsWare custom Info Windows in GMaps v2 are drawn as Bitmaps. I need normal dynamic View, so I rendering my own and I try to do this effectievely

Comment: Most likely, you are going to have to change your design, either to settle for a regular info window, or have your separate `View` have a fixed location (e.g., sidebar), or otherwise avoid the per-frame calls into Maps V2.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need dynamic Marker Info Window by the app design, I did it, it runs as smoothly as possible, but sometimes GC_EXPLICIT calls produce fps lags.

Comment: And if the fps lags are unacceptable, most likely, you are going to have to change your design, either to settle for a regular info window, or have your separate View have a fixed location (e.g., sidebar), or otherwise avoid the per-frame calls into Maps V2.